# Bath setup: Hand Shower and shower head on independent valves and trim

Tags: plumbing, shower

Appreciate opinion, if following setup is plumbing-sound:

Basement bath, no tub, full 5ft shower. I would like a shower head and a hand-shower on completely independent mixing values(instead of diverter). So 2 values with identical 2 trims .
My plumber already setup one valve and calls me saying "this setup does not make sense + space is tight."

Trying to get a second opinion.
Any downsides to having two valves? Doesn't that add flexibility for future modification, i.e. having two plumbing lines. Why do people feel two trim/knobs as un-intuitive?

Pic attached. If there is not enough space on left of the shower-head/valve, I am open to having hand-shower&shower-bar and its valve/trim on the wall to the left.

Thanks a bunch.

[image][image: Wall with shower-head and valve added]

Comment: It looks tight to me if you want the same valve and trim. It looks like your plumber did a nice job sweating the fittings.